# What's the variable scope within `class_eval` string?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

I am using `class_eval` to write code to be executed under the context of current class. In the following code, I want to add a counter for changes of attribute values.

```
class Class
  def attr_count(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name # create the attribute's getter
    class_eval %Q{
      @count = 0
      def #{attr_name}= (attr_name)
        @attr_name = attr_name
        @count += 1
      end

      def #{attr_name}
        @attr_name
      end
    }
    end
  end
class Foo
  attr_count :bar
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 1
```

My understanding of `class_eval` is that it evaluates the block **in the context of the runtime class** - in my case, under `class Foo`. I expect the above code **runs similar as**:

```
class Foo
  attr_count :bar
  @count = 0
  def bar= (attr_name)
    @attr_name = attr_name
    @count += 1
  end

  def bar
    @attr_name
  end
end
```

However the above code resulted in error saying, the error is caused by `@count += 1`. I cannot figure out why `@count` has `nil:NilClass` as its super?

```
(eval):5:in `bar=': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

On the other hand, @selman has given a solution to put `@count` assignment within the instance method and it works.

```
class Class
  def attr_count(attr_name)
    #...
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{attr_name}= (attr_name)
        @attr_name = attr_name
        if @count
          @count += 1
        else
          @count = 1
        end
      end
      #...
    }
  end
end
```

Why changes the variable scope works? How does `class_eval` execute its following string?

Comment: How did you like your CS169 class?  :)

Answer (score 12):

it is not about `class_eval` it is about `@count`. if you define this variable at class level it will be a `class instance variable` not an `instance variable`.

```
class Class
  def attr_count(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name # create the attribute's getter
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{attr_name}= (attr_name)
        @attr_name = attr_name
        if @count
          @count += 1
        else
          @count = 1
        end
      end

      def #{attr_name}
        @attr_name
      end
    }
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_count :bar
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 1
```

Comment: It works. I am still confused by the difference between `@count` and `@@count` in the `class_eval` method. My understanding is 1.The string passed to `class_eval` will be evaluated at runtime - when the `class Foo` is called.  2. `@count` should be an instance variable for all instances of `Foo`.   Why use class variable `@@count` makes it behaves like **instance variable**?  I know the topic is complicated, do you have some reference which I could read?

Comment: Hi, @selmen. I found `@@count` doesn't really behave as a instance variable. It behaves as class variable. That's not what I expected

Comment: It works. Thx. Compare with your and mine, the problem seems to lie at the scope of `@count`. Why the `@count` assigned directly in `class_eval` (in my code) couldn't be accessed by methods defined in `class_eval`?