# How to use class_eval for multi attributes value

Tags: ruby

I tried to to extend the [code from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466624/whats-the-variable-scope-within-class-eval-string) for keeping records of an attribute value. However, my code fails in the case of more than one attributes. Here is the code:

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    attr_name = attr_name.to_s
    attr_reader attr_name

    ah=attr_name+"_history"
    attr_reader ah 

    class_eval %Q{          
      def #{attr_name}= (attr_name)
        @attr_name=attr_name

        if @ah == nil
          @ah=[nil]
        end
        @ah.push(attr_name)
      end
      def #{ah}
        @ah
      end  

      def #{attr_name}
        @attr_name
      end
     }
  end
end
```

Here a dummy class for testing

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor_with_history :bar
  attr_accessor_with_history :bar1
end

f = Foo.new
f.bar = 1
f.bar = 2
f.bar1 = 5
p f.bar_history  
p f.bar1_history
```

For some reason, `f.bar` and `f.bar1` both return `5` and `f.bar_history = f.bar1_history = [nil, 1, 2, 5]`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Where is the code for the `#{attr_name}_history` method?

Comment: oops, I did not copy the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `@ah` and `@attr_name` instead of `@#{ah}` and `@#{attr_name}` when getting/setting in the methods. This meant that they were always setting and returning the same instance variable, instead of different, dynamically named ones.

```
class Class
  def attr_accessor_with_history(attr_name)
    class_eval %{
      attr_reader :#{attr_name}, :#{attr_name}_history

      def #{attr_name}=(value)
        @#{attr_name} = value
        @#{attr_name}_history ||= [nil]
        @#{attr_name}_history << value
      end
     }
  end
end
```

I've also generally cleaned up your code a little to make it (I think) clearer and more concise.

Comment: Wow. that works. Thanks a bunch (for cleaning my code also :D). By the way, is there any good and short intro book to Ruby (or tutorial) that you can recommend? I borrowed "The ruby programming language" but it is kinda wordy.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/158402) `:)`. And that book (aka the pickaxe) is considered to be the definitive Ruby book, though some claim it to be a bit dense (I've only read it in piecemeal so I can't really comment too much). [Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/) is also quite revered. Most of my Ruby knowledge comes from working with others and reading lots and lots of code and, of course, writing a lot too. (That said, no short tutorial will get into the sort of metaprogramming you're doing here.)